# Cannot define an enumeration after including windows.h : syntax error

Tags: c++, windows, syntax-error, visual-studio-2015

We chased down the origin of a strange syntax error from a big codebase. The following code:

```
#include <windows.h>

enum Element
{
    IN,    //(a)
    OUT
};         //(b)
```

Fails to compile under Visual Studio 2015, giving the errors:

```
(a) error C2059: syntax error: ','
(b) error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
(b) error C2059: syntax error: '}'
```

- Is this code illegal ? (I hope not)
- If it is legal, is this a known issue ? With a workaround ?

Comment: I'm guessing the names `IN` and `OUT` are defined directly or indirectly in `windows.h`.

Comment: @juanchopanza And you are right: IN is defined... Do you know a way to still use it as an enumerator value ? (we have quite a lot of client code already using this name).

Comment: try to use an `enum class`

Comment: Use `#undef` to remove the definition.

Comment: I seem to have tracked down these macros to `Include\shared\bcrypt.h`, there are indeed `IN` and `OUT` macros defined. Also in `lmcons.h`, `rpcdce.h`, and `wincrypt.h` among many others throughout the windows headers.

Comment: You can possibly get away with including less of `windows.h` by defining `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` first. This gets rid of a lot of cruft that's only in there by default to keep ancient programs from throwing compiler errors.

Comment: @Joey Actually, defining WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN does not prevent those symbols definitions.

Comment: @AdN: Hence »possibly«. I couldn't check, but without that define there are lots of weird things you otherwise only get rid of by including certain header files in a specific order and other arcane fixes, so that was my first thought.

Answer (score 2):

Those are macros defined in windows headers, under VS2015 inside minwinddef.h. I would recomend to change naming convention you are using, instead of `IN` and `OUT` use `In` and `Out` - leave all uppercase names to macros. If you cannot change names - then you are left with using `#undef`, it should be safe if you are not using IN and OUT inside your code, as far as I know those are used only to indicate whether parameters are expected to be used as return values or not.

Answer (score 0):

`IN` and `OUT` are macros defined in windows.h.

```
// Windows.h:79-84
#ifndef IN
#define IN
#endif

#ifndef OUT
#define OUT
#endif
```

Since you're using `windows.h`, my recommendation is not to #undefine them(you might be using something from Windows.h that depends on this macros), instead change your code:

```
// Note: as pointed out by  πάντα ῥεῖ:
// Prefixed _ are reserved for standerd implementations.
// Perhaps you should use In and Out instead.
enum Element
{
    _IN,   
    _OUT
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly, changing their value would be very costly, as they are already used in a lot of client code.

Comment: Prefixed `_` are reserved for standerd implementations.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, is just an illustrative example. ;), but good point, I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`IN` and `OUT` are too generic names and, as you've seen, the probability of a collision is high.

As you've seen, they are already used in `windows.h`. Try to put them in a namespace, try to use an `enum class` or use more descriptive names, in order to avoid name collisions. You can also `#undef` these macros but it's not a good idea in my opinion.